Madelung constant convergence and order of summation for 3D infinite-series
I am trying to calculate the Madelung constants for the ordering of an experimental NaAsS2 structure in a fully undistorted face-centered cubic lattice. I originally wrote python code that will calculate steps of the series by expanding cubes of ions, so each step increases the dimensions of our cube by 2 bonds (one in both the + and - direction) along the x, y, and z-axis. But the series alternates and diverges for this method/structure.
We had the idea to change our code to expand by unit cells rather than ions so that our overall calculated cell is always neutrally charged, doing this the series seems to numerically converge rather quickly (each step increases each lattice dimension by 2 respective lattice vectors (again one in both the + & - direction). The issue is that the series is converging to different values depending on the unit cell used. Using a rectangular-prism unit cell, all Madelung constants for atoms of the same environment converge to the same number(as expected), this is not the case when a non rectangular-prism unit cell is used. Furthermore, the number that the constant is converging to changes depending on the ratio of dimensions of the unit cell. When I change the charges of ions to be equivalent to NaCl, I get convergence to the correct value for any rectangular-prism unit cell no matter the dimensions(as long as its a valid unit cell).
My instinct says just use a cubic unit cell because then the series is almost equivalent to a cubic expansion at certain steps, and most of the literature I'm finding is recommending expanding by a cube, but all references I can find only talk about very basic compounds like NaCl.
I'm wondering if there is a concrete answer for which order of summation will converge to the correct value, and if there even is a "correct" value for a structure like this. I also want to ask if anyone knows how the Madelung constant for NaCl was determined. I don't think its provable that the series mathematically converges, so how do we know for certain the value is 1.74756 (for Cl)?
If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it a lot. I am confident the code is right, I am more looking for information on why certain orders of summation would or wouldn't converge to the "correct value" and how to determine what this order is for different orderings of ions.
Here are 2 of the unit cells I've tested and the respective approximate values they seem to converge to.
Cell 1:
Lattice : 
2 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 2
Ion coordinates(fractional):
0.0 0.0 0.0 Na
0.0 0.5 0.5 Na
0.5 0.0 0.5 As
0.5 0.5 0.0 As
0.0 0.5 0.0 S
0.0 0.0 0.5 S
0.5 0.0 0.0 S
0.5 0.5 0.5 S
Madelung constants: 
Na = -2.8913313646878462
As = -4.098927002263366
S_1 = 2.6185889138106204
S_2 = 4.371669453147124
Cell 2:
Lattice:
2 0 0
0 4 0
0 0 2
Ion coordinates(fractional):
0.0 0.0 0.0 Na
0.0 0.25 0.5 Na
0.0 0.5 0.0 Na
0.0 0.75 0.5 Na
0.5 0.0 0.5 As
0.5 0.25 0.0 As
0.5 0.5 0.5 As
0.5 0.75 0.0 As
0.0 0.25 0.0 S
0.0 0.0 0.5 S
0.5 0.0 0.0 S
0.5 0.25 0.5 S
0.0 0.75 0.0 S
0.0 0.5 0.5 S
0.5 0.5 0.0 S
0.5 0.75 0.5 S
Madelung constants: 
Na = -3.0524287199706657
As = -3.9378296565143907
S_1 = 2.4574274160160074
S_2 = 4.532781217186226

You may have rediscovered this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

@ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, but that also applies to the NaCl Madelung constants right? So how do we know that summing by expanding cubes gives the correct value?

Do you know the analytical expression of the series you are numerically summing?

The NaCl case converges when you sum as successively bigger cubes, adding one layer by one layer. It diverges if you use spherical shells, and it is easy to see why, unless you make the smart move of summing as double-layers, because then the offending sum will stop alternating. Madelung constants are not easy to sum. You should also try decomposing into two parts, a part you sum by Fourier series, and another part in real space, where in both parts you avoid the divergence.

@naturallyInconsistent that is our reasoning for expanding by layers of unit cell, to keep the charge neutral. It just confuses me why it converges to different numbers depending on the shape of the unit cell you expand by. The 2nd cell I gave in the post is just 2 of the first cell stacked in the y direction

I'm not sure what it is you did; if you have two of the first cell stacked in the y direction, then your growing lattice is just a different shape, and so I would not be surprised by having a different converged value. You need to respect the overall symmetries when you attempt such computations.

@naturallyInconsistent My question is why is a cube the "correct" shape to expand by, is there a mathematical reason every axis needs to have increased equally? My gut says the cubic one should be correct but I'm worried that I'm not being thorough enough by intuitively assuming that. I'd think the limit to infinity should be the same for any rectangular prism. And expanding by either of those cells gets the correct constant for NaCl when I change the charges to -1 and 1.

Ultimately, the only correct situation is that the correct shape has to match the actual finite sized system's shape. Especially if it is not converging to the same values, then you have to take this into account.
